Swing UI performance considerations - nested layouts vs single grid
Basic question is are there serious performance differences between nesting Swing layouts vs using a single parent complex grid-based layout (e.g. FormLayout or MigLayout)?
For example, a layout like this:

Could probably be represented with a single parent FormLayout with ~6 main columns (+7 "gap" columns if you use FormLayout).
However one could also use a more nested approach, with a single column parent, and ~5 rows of children, each with its own layout (perhaps another grid, or something simpler).
In my opinion the nesting makes the child layouts a little easier to adjust and work with, especially if you expect changes in the future, but the single grid parent is obviously more concise.
So to re-state my question - Does nesting the layouts have serious performance impacts? I would assume that for minor nesting like my example it would not (correct me if im wrong) but would the approach change if you needed many more levels of nesting?
Or is there a best-practice to all this that Im missing (I have not found one)?

"Does nesting the layouts have serious performance impacts?" No.  I commonly build Swing layouts with three levels of nesting.  I occasionally use four levels.  I can't imagine how you would use more than five levels of nesting.  Generally, you construct your entire Swing layout in the initialization.  Then you use the various JPanels.

Even a simple file chooser exceeds 5 levels: dialog • root pane • layered pane • content pane • JFileChooser • file pane • yet another panel • scroll pane • viewport • cellRendererPane • cell renderer Note that nested components do not only affect the visual layout, they also impact operations like targeting mouse events. Since such operations do not ask the layout manager, a flat, single parent layout would always end up in a linear search through all components. So, unless you override the contains method, nesting components wins. But you rarely have so many components that it matters.
